# How to keep using a value after pushing it into a vector?

Tags: vector, rust, borrow-checker

So I want to keep using a value after pushing it into a vector, but when I add it to the vector it takes ownership control over the variable, so when I want to make reference to it again I can't. How should I approach this scenario?

```
fn scan_recursive(dir: &Path) -> io::Result<Vec<PathBuf>> {
    let mut files = Vec::new(); // Create a mutable vector to store the files.

    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let path = entry.path();

        if path.is_file() {
            files.push(path);
        }

        if path.is_dir() { // ERROR: path is no longer valid
            files.append(&mut scan_recursive(&path)?);
        }
    }

    Ok(files)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler does not know if the first `if` is executed and cannot tell if the `path` variable is consumed or not, so it assumes that it always is, and the lifetime of `path` ends after the push to the vector.

Given that your two `if`s are mutually exclusive (the `path` is either a file or a directory) you can use `if ... else`, which will let the compiler deduce that if the `path` is not a file, the variables has not been consumed in the `if` branch and it will still be available in the `else` branch.

```rust
if path.is_file() {
  files.push(path);
}
else if path.is_dir() {
  files.append(&mut scan_recursive(&path)?);
}
```